# Calculating Path (Polygon) of Path with Stroke - Javascript or Pseudocode

Tags: javascript, graphics, path, polygon, stroke

So I have an array of points (x, y) that form a path. I need to calculate the points of a surrounding polygon. Essentially `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` if you're familiar with iOS. Unfortunately, ObjC is not an option. I need to implement it either in Javascript, PHP, etc.

```
    -------
    |  |  |
    |  |  |
    \  \  \
     \  \  \
      \  \  \
       \  \  \
        \  \  \-----------
         \  \----------- |
          \---------------
```

Apologize for the bad ascii art.

I have a semi-working version in Javascript, but I have issues with corners.

```
        function pathToPoly(points) {
            var numOfPoints = points.length;

            var fullPath = [];
            var leftPaths = [];
            var rightPaths = [];

            var pad = 20;

            for(var i=0; i<numOfPoints-1; i++) {
                var pointA = points[i];
                var pointB = points[i+1];

                var slope = (pointB.Y - pointA.Y) / (pointB.X - pointA.X);
                var inverseSlope = -1 / slope;
                var inverseAngle = Math.atan(inverseSlope);

                if(inverseAngle < 0) {
                    leftPaths.push({
                        X1: pointA.X - pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y1: pointA.Y - pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle),
                        X2: pointB.X - pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y2: pointB.Y - pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle)
                    });

                    rightPaths.push({
                        X1: pointA.X + pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y1: pointA.Y + pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle),
                        X2: pointB.X + pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y2: pointB.Y + pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle)
                    });
                } else {
                    rightPaths.push({
                        X1: pointA.X - pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y1: pointA.Y - pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle),
                        X2: pointB.X - pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y2: pointB.Y - pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle)
                    });

                    leftPaths.push({
                        X1: pointA.X + pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y1: pointA.Y + pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle),
                        X2: pointB.X + pad * Math.cos(inverseAngle),
                        Y2: pointB.Y + pad * Math.sin(inverseAngle)
                    });
                }

                if(drawSides) {
                    var leftSide = leftPaths[i];
                    var rightSide = rightPaths[i];

                    context.beginPath();

                    context.moveTo(leftSide.X1, leftSide.Y1);
                    context.lineTo(leftSide.X2, leftSide.Y2);

                    context.lineWidth = 1;
                    context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
                    context.stroke();

                    context.beginPath();

                    context.moveTo(rightSide.X1, rightSide.Y1);
                    context.lineTo(rightSide.X2, rightSide.Y2);

                    context.lineWidth = 1;
                    context.strokeStyle = 'cyan';
                    context.stroke();
                }
            }

            for(var i=0; i<numOfPoints-1; i++) {
                var line1 = leftPaths[i];
                var line2 = leftPaths[i+1];

                fullPath.push({
                    X: line1.X1,
                    Y: line1.Y1
                });
                fullPath.push({
                    X: line1.X2,
                    Y: line1.Y2,
                });

                if(line2) {
                    fullPath.push({
                        X: line2.X1,
                        Y: line2.Y1,
                    });
                }
            }

            fullPath.push({
                X: leftPaths[numOfPoints-2].X2,
                Y: leftPaths[numOfPoints-2].Y2
            });

            for(var i=numOfPoints-2; i>=0; i--) {
                var line1 = rightPaths[i];
                var line2 = rightPaths[i-1];

                fullPath.push({
                    X: line1.X2,
                    Y: line1.Y2
                });

                fullPath.push({
                    X: line1.X1,
                    Y: line1.Y1,
                });
                if(line2) {
                    fullPath.push({
                        X: line2.X2,
                        Y: line2.Y2,
                    });
                }
            }

            fullPath.push({
                X: rightPaths[0].X1,
                Y: rightPaths[0].Y1
            });

            return fullPath;
        }
```

This code draws parallel lines on each side of every segment, and connects them. But for turns, my methods creates an INVALID polygon. The sides "swap" and generate an "inverse" area. And being able to calculate the area is crucial for my application.

Example (my reputation is too low to post images): The blue works fine, but the red fails (notice how the bottom right turn, the sides swap).

```
![example](http://www.originalfunction.com/stackoverflow_16590082-1.png)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to compute the output points, as opposed to drawing the polygon on something. What are you going to do with the result?

Comment: I do eventually draw the polygon out, but I calculate additional stuff for the polygon. This is for a game I'm programming.

Comment: OK. Can you give an example of how it fails (show input points, expected output, actual output)?

Comment: (I don't promise that I'll have time to figure out the problem, but it seems to me more likely that someone can help you if you show more explicitly what failure you're trying to solve.)

Comment: Looks like it fails when and only when the line bends at an acute angle (based on a small sample), correct? I haven't gone thru the algorithm thoroughly, but just an educated guess: I wonder if you've taken into account the fact that for atan(x), there are two right answers, and the js function may not be returning the one you're expecting? atan2() eliminates the ambiguity, if you can use it.

Comment: @LarsH thanks. atan2 indeed fixed most of the issues!

Comment: Nice. I'll put it into an answer so you can give me proper credit. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it fails when and only when the line bends at an acute angle (based on a small sample), correct?

I haven't gone thru the algorithm thoroughly, but just an educated guess: I wonder if you've taken into account the fact that for `atan(slope)`, there are two right answers, and the javascript `atan()` function may not be returning the answer you're expecting (180 degrees off)?

[atan2(y, x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) eliminates this ambiguity, if you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javascript Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) for offsetting polygons (closed path). To offset a polyline (open path), you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19269009/1691517). There is a [demo](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/main_demo.html), where you can test offsetting polygons.

[image]
[image]