# Geometry (CONVOLUTION) function with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geometry

I try to do this 3 months - I need to create a polygon by route direction like here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/olGmuN6.png]

so so I write this:

```
directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        var r = [];
        var z = 0.5;
        var bla = result.routes[0].overview_path;
        for(var i=0 in result.routes[0].overview_path) {
            r.push(new google.maps.LatLng(bla[i].lat()+z, bla[i].lng()-z));
        }
        bla.reverse();
        for(var x=0 in bla) {
            r.push(new google.maps.LatLng(bla[x].lat()-z, bla[x].lng()+z));
        }

        var prva = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: result.routes[0].overview_path,
            strokeColor: "#00000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

        prva.setMap(map);

        druga = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: r,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        druga.setMap(map);

    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
```

but in some cases is good in some cases not, so my code produce this:

**BAD case**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5lqL.png]

**GOOD case:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH88N.jpg]

So how I can solve this problem to get nice polygon by route direction ??? Does someody have idea?

How I can implement this into my code:

CONVOLUTION ALGORITHM

[image: http://i.imm.io/1gMu5.png]

Is there any solution for my problem?

Is there some other way than this to create what I need?

Comment: I can't view the images, but what is the problem you are having?  Some more description would be good.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w5lqL.png    -      http://i.stack.imgur.com/DH88N.jpg

Comment: This is....let me guess, the 5th time you ask this question( [**1**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19006196) [**2**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19035243) [**3**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19080976) [**4**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19083476) )? Do you assume that you'll get better answers when you switch your account or delete the questions(your recent questions have been more detailed)? When you take a look 
at http://i.stack.imgur.com/us7yG.png you should recognize that the result would not be usable as a Maps-polygon, because the intersections will be subtracted there.

Comment: ok, I just try to find answer becouse I dont do this 3 months

Comment: @drMolle what you suggest, how I can solve my problem? I really need to do this

Comment: I would try to achieve it by using  a canvas-line as map-overlay.

Comment: please show me example in jsfiddle

Comment: Try it yourself at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: yes but there is not example of what i need

Comment: please show me on my example: http://jsbin.com/iviYiyA/1/edit please i will be very very happy.THANKS!!!

Comment: SO is a community for developers, not for code-requests. start developing

Comment: ok, but i dont know how this i can solve really

Comment: i try this http://jsbin.com/iviYiyA/3/edit, and draw line as you say, but there is problem when i zoom map, zooming change the stroke

Comment: I didn't suggest you to draw a `google.maps.Polyline` . It would be nice when it would be that easy, but the strokeWeight of a `google.maps.Polyline` is limited, (you may have noticed that the line doesn't have a weight of 200 although the setting is 200 )

Comment: so what I need to do else? please explain me

Comment: Why do you need to do something else...this question has an accepted answer, so your problem must be solved.

Comment: I think you should read about bezier curves http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/

Comment: ok, cool, thanks, but how i can implement that?

Comment: please update your example with this beyier code

Comment: so, can you help me with beyier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm to produce the second image is quite simple geometrically. I'll write you some pseudocode, assuming you have an array of x,y arrays:

```
coordinates = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2] ... [xn,yn]]
leftcoords = []
rightcoords = []

projectionwidth = 1        # How wide the path is

for each coordinate in coordinates:
    pathvector = coordinate(index + 1) - coordinate(index - 1)
    normpathvector = pathvector/(length(pathvector))
    perpvector = projectionwidth*[-normpathvector[1],normpathvector[0]]
    leftcoords.append(coordinate + perpvector)
    rightcoords.append(coordinate - perpvector)
```

You have to take care at the end of the path to only choose coordinates ahead or behind, but you get the idea. You end up with three sets of coordinate trajectories. You can set it up to average several points if you'd like to smooth the path.

Ok, so here is code that works, but you'll have to do some work to smooth it out to account for the jitter in the path. My suggestion would be to average several previous points, or just grab a point several back.

http://jsbin.com/uTATePe/2/

Comment: please write example on jsfiddle

Comment: here is my code from example: http://jsbin.com/iviYiyA/1/edit how to implement this your code into example???

Comment: yes, but again I dont get almost ideal area by directions so like on image I put in my question... what I need to do?

Comment: The problem is solve in one part... your code not render region like on image I put above http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZzl.png ... I will solve problem when I get region by direction like on this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZzl.png