# How to 'smooth' inconsistent coordinate data?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinates, geo

Using LeafletJS, I have a set of coordinates sorted by chronological order.  When plotting the coordinates as a path on a map, we should expect a continuous line :

1-2-3-4

However when the coordinates are plotted on a map, the resulting path skips all over the place.  The coordinates should create a continuous line from West to East.  It seems as though the coordinates are not in true chronological order :

[image: unexpected behavior]

`42.423892,-89.154819
42.420308,-89.116814
42.525,-90.9139
42.525,-90.9139
42.41258,-89.037483
42.407692,-88.960898
42.401454,-88.910693
42.414908,-89.06712
42.404899,-88.921487
42.404899,-88.921487
42.410811,-89.005993`

What would be the best approach to 'smooth' the data so that the coordinates do not jump from place to place.

Alternatively, is it possible to find the general path the coordinates make and sort the coordinates so that the path does not jump back on itself?

A pastebin of the coordinates in question can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/1pE9XCHy)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19168516/1972493.. might be of help. Also you could just use 1D convolution with a vector [1,1,1,..] n times to smooth the x and y coordinates independently.

Comment: See here for a convolution implementation https://gist.github.com/PhotonEE/7671999 Also it looks like your data could use a sort in advance of smoothing.